# QField crashing unexpectedly with no error

Tags: qfield

I have a QField project that crashes intermittently with no error message. When I open the project again, there is no text in the log.

Is there a way to turn logging on to try and find what is causing the issue?

Comment: There was an issue with labels crashing QField, it might still exists. It's worth a try to just turn labels off

Comment: It seems premature to close this post. It may be a known issue rather than a bug.